# Dynamic linq: Is there a way to access object data by index?

Tags: c#, casting, dynamic-linq, indexer

I need some in-memory filtering with Dynamic Linq. 
My objects have only a indexer:

```
public  object this[int index] { }
```

The access to my data is like: object[0], object[1],...

So my query is like this:

```
// get FilterText from user at runtime
// eg. filterText can be: [0] > 100 and [1] = "wpf"
collection.AsQueryable().where(filterText);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some news for you.

It is actually possible... BUT! (Yes, there´s a but).

I assume you are using the dynamic Linq library. You must then use the "it"-keyword to be able to specify the current object to which you wish to apply your indexing operation.

However... The return datatype of your indexer is object, so you will not be able to write [0] > 100 and [1] = "wpf" because of data type mismatch.

Also, even if you derive from DynamicObject and would add the properties at runtime, those properties would not be resolved at runtime by the dynamic linq library in it´s current state. You would just get a field or property does not exist in type xxx.

There are several solutions to this, of which some you may accept as being a solution.

- One ugly solution, if you have a limited number of datatypes, say n
  (where n < the number of types in .NET), you could use n
  indexers with parameter matching and get the datatype you want. For
  example if you have mostly ints and some strings:

  ```
  it[0] > 100 AND it[1, "dummy"] = "wpf" //The dummy parameter allows you to specify return type.
  ```
- Another ugly solution, Dynamic Linq has support for using the
  ToString() and Convert-methods, so, you could for instance write the
  same query as above:

  ```
  Convert.ToDouble(it[0]) > 100 AND it[1].ToString() = "wpf".
  ```
- A third ugly solution, you could use a convention where you wrap
  statements in a way which tells you how to convert the data. For
  example, you could write:

  ```
  it[0] > 100 AND it{1} = "wpf"
  ```

  And replace "it[" with "Convert.ToDouble(it[" and so on...

If I´m correct, I think that you can´t use a generic indexer with the library either. And Convert.ChangeType does you no good in this case since the return type is still object.

Maybe I or someone else will rewrite the library some time to support these kinds of things, but I have no time to do so in the near future (some weeks).

Well, I´m sorry, but I´ve got to be somewhere in 15 min, so we´ll have to take the nicer solutions later I hope!

*teleporting myself to the meeting*

**UPDATE:**

I think I may have found a solution to your (and my) problem!

In the DLINQ library, you could add a member in the IxxxSignatures interface(s) for the type for which you would want to be able to work with.

So, I added (for example) in the IEqualitySignatures:

```
void F(Object x, Int32 y);
```

And modified the (in this case) ParseComparison-method in the else block like this.

```
left = Expression.Convert(left, right.Type);
```

And, believe it or not, it worked :)

I have not tested all kinds of operations, since I have not added the signatures for the other types and operations, but it should be quite straight forward to do!

**UPDATE**

Updated some minor stuff above..

I´m experimenting some more on this and while it might not be the prettiest solution either, you could do something like this (DataObject is just a DynamicObject with an indexer):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DynamicTest()
    {
        List<DataObject> dataObjects = new List<DataObject>();

        dynamic firstObject = new DataObject();
        dynamic secondObject = new DataObject();

        firstObject.dblProp = 10.0;
        firstObject.intProp = 8;
        firstObject.strProp = "Hello";

        secondObject.dblProp = 8.0;
        secondObject.intProp = 8;
        secondObject.strProp = "World";

        dataObjects.Add(firstObject);
        dataObjects.Add(secondObject);

        /* Notice the different types */
        string newQuery = FormatQuery("dblProp > 9.0 AND intProp = 8 AND strProp = 'Hello'");

        var result = dataObjects.Where(newQuery);

        Assert.AreEqual(result.Count(), 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(result.First(), firstObject);
    }
```

And some kind of format method like (pretend I´ve written a complete method):

```
    public string FormatQuery(string query)
    {
        query = query.Replace('\'', '\"');

        string[] operators = new string[] { "<", ">", "!=", "<=", ">=", "<>", "=" };

        string[] parts = query.Split();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (operators.Contains(parts[i]))
            {
                parts[i - 1] = "it[\"" + parts[i - 1] + "\"]";
            }
        }

        return String.Join(" ", parts);
    }
```

We could of course have an extension-method instead.

Or... We could put the method in the DLINQ lib using something like (not saying it a good idea though):

```
if (typeof(T).GetInterface("IDynamicMetaObjectProvider", true) != null)
    whereClause = whereClause.FormatQuery();
```

And, check if the type implements a string-indexer of course, something like (ignoring IndexerName attribute here):

```
if (t.GetType().GetProperty("Item") != null)
```

which would enable "normal users" to write:

```
data.Where("dblProp > 9.0 AND intProp = 8 AND strProp = 'Hello'")
```

Well, maybe it´s not good to have that stuff in there, but you get the point. You could have! :)

Comment: really? I don't think you need to do that ugly things, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just trying to make the point that the type is object and therefore some operations do not apply without conversion. 

It would be nice to have an implicit conversion. Maybe DLINQ could look at the right side value and convert the left side to it (I know, it already does some of this, but libs could always do more for you :P).

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. I now understand the background and whats possible. But I am not really satisfied :(. 

I tried this day to

Comment: As you described the problem is the type conversion. I can't find a way to dynamically change the type. Nor to get the type with reflection and convert it. 

So the next step I will try ist to get an element of my collection. And than with reflection I will use the indexer this[n] to get all elements and to get the type of this elements. In a switch statement I can than add conversion methods. So I get something as your second example.

Comment: what happens if `left` cannot by converted to `right.Type`? An exception?

Comment: Yes there you will get:
Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.InvalidCastException" ist in Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly aufgetreten.

The problem occur, if your value is of type float. DLINQ will always convert the number which is in the filterString to double.

This will ocur, when the query is executed. A little bit bad do see the error later. And no detailed error message for the user. No position and no expected types....

Beside this, it will work :). Thanks for this great update. I was on the same way, but find the solution.

Comment: Sorry I mean ...didn't find the solution.

Comment: Johan, I updated your post regarding your format ideas. Tomorrow I willl work improving the type, if it is possible!? And do some tests. If it is possible and you are interrested in, we can interchange our DLINQ.

Comment: Johan, I see my update was deleted. It's too bad about the time I spend for writing and formatting. But if you are interrested in, I send it to your eMail. I think it was deleted, because it was a answer to your format update and not an answer/extension to the original problem!? Perhaps we have to open a new issue for this.

Comment: @Schorsch and Johan, does what you guys discuss here relate somehow to `dynamic` objects, like in Johan's other question?

Comment: @Krizz no it didn't. Perhaps it's similar. We discuss about indexer and the returntype **object**.

Answer (score 1):

You either use DynamicLinq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx or you build your expression trees using reflection. A lot of people prefer the Dynamic Linq library for this; I've never used it myself, I've taken the reflection approach.

Comment: Not sure who gave you -1.  This is a perfectly valid answer. +1

Comment: Thanks, @EBarr. I was wondering why was downvoted myself even though it is correct.

Comment: Thanks to your comment. I use DLinq library. I extended it now to translate [n] to it[n]. But the problem is the type conversion. See my answer to the other statements.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to prepend your indexer with `it` which is equivalent in DynamicLinq language to `this` in C#.

So, you just need `it[1] == "wpf"`.

However, there is some more complication due to the fact your indexer returns `object`. For class types (including `string`) you are fine, DLinq will promote everything as needed.

However, for value types like `int`s, you will have to do `Int32(it[0]) > 10`.

Comment: No it isn't the full set of funktionality as I have with it[1].ToString(). In this case I can also use "=,>,<". 

To surround or add a method is not the problem. The problem is to get the correct type to add this methotd. See my comment to the first answwer.

Comment: @Schorsch sorry, I can't get what you mean. Can you please explain? "The problem is to get the correct type to add this methotd." - to get correct type of what? to add what method?

Comment: @Schorsch, I have updated my answer. Hopefully it´s useful to you!

Comment: @Krizz Thanks for your thoughts. I meant the problem is to get the real type of the value out of my model. Because the result of this[n] or it[n] is an object. But Johan has excellent solutions to handle this.